# babeltrace Format "text" unknown

Tags: babeltrace

I am trying to use the babeltrace lib to read a trace file.
So here it the flow:
1. babeltrace /var/log/some_trace > trc.txt
2. My program does this in trying to add a trace after creating context:

```
code
int err = bt_context_add_trace(ctx, path, "text", nullptr,
    nullptr, nullptr);
code
```

3. Compile and Run the program gives this error:
   code
   [error] [Context] Format "text" unknown.
   code

The idea is that I have trace generated on multiple machines - and though I can use my program to directly read the binary trace files on my local system, for other systems, I convert the trace using babeltrace and then process all these traces together.

The package I have installed is this:
babeltrace-devel-1.2.4-1.el7.x86_64

Comment: * I can just collect the binary traces and run my program on that.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of `bt_context_add_trace` is the input format's name. For binary (CTF) traces, you will want to use the `"ctf"` format, rather than `"text"`. You can use the latter as your output format, however.